# How to point jmeter properties path to maven downloaded jmeter jar path?

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am quite new to Jmeter and trying to code and run jmeter using JAVA by following:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/
https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java

```
  if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
  File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");

            if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                //JMeter Engine
                StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
                JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
```

Cannot I use like this

```
 StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
                JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome();
                JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties();
```

I am getting an error when I use the above code

ERROR org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Can't compute checksum for saveservice properties file
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: JMeter requires the checksum of saveservice properties file to continue

Cannot we point to the jmeter jar downloaded through Maven instead of pointing to jmeter property path ? Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

The [error](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.java#L223) you're getting indicates that JMeter fails to read [saveservice.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/saveservice.properties) file.

The file is not a part of any JMeter .jar libraries, you will need to have it in the "bin" subfolder of the folder you specify via [JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#setJMeterHome-java.lang.String-) function.

If you invoke [JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getJMeterHome--) function prior to setting it - you will get `null` and if you refer the value somewhere else - you will get a [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Assuming all above:

1. Make sure to set JMeter home via the aforementioned function prior to running the test
2. Make sure to have `saveservice.properties` in that folder

---

It might be easier to use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool for unattended programmatic JMeter tests execution, Taurus provides possibility to [execute existing JMeter tests and create new ones](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) using simple [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) syntax. See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/) article for more information on the concept

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the response. Do you have a sample Taurus project for Jemeter that I can run on Eclipse using Maven ? If so , will you be able to share the link . This will be good starting point for me to learn Taurus. I understand the benefits of Taurus from the links you have provided here

Comment: Taurus is a [Python](https://www.python.org/)-based tool and Maven is a Java build/dependency management solution, they're absolutely different beasts.  If you want to run an existing JMeter test with Maven it's better to consider [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the response. Do you know of a sample project for Jmeter that I can run on Eclipse using Maven. My requirement is to run performance testing in Java using Jmeter with all the  detailed HTML and graphs availability